# How do I get the all the basic binary blocks containing a special instruction like 'CALL' or 'RET' using python in Ghidra?

Tags: ghidra, python

I am using Ghidra to do reverse engineering of an ARM binary. I want to print the disassembly of all blocks across all functions containing a specific instruction like 'CALL' or 'RET'. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like:

```
# get all functions
functions = program.getFunctionManager().getFunctions(True)
for function in functions:
    cur = function.getEntryPoint()
    while cur:
        inst = getInstructionAt(cur)
        if inst:
            # add similar check for call instruction
            if "RET" in inst.getMnemonicString():
                #do something
                print(inst)
                # this will break when function returns
                break
        cur = cur.next()
```

I wrote this script for x86 binaries, but it would work fine with arm as well (you may have to do minor changes), as the api is identical.